# How to send a continuous stream of bytes to multiple clients

Tags: rust, tcp, io, udp, rust-cargo

**UPDATE:**

I made a bit of progress using TCP as a means for communication. However, I'm not quite there yet.
I solved most of the problems below, but there are some new ones.
The idea is that there's a separate thread generating random numbers which sends those into a message queue.
Clients can connect and will be handled in separate threads as well. They should ideally all get the same random numbers from the broadcasting queue.
This works like a charm, until the buffer of the queue is reached. Then, the queue is full and no more messages can be sent.
I haven't found a way removing the sent items from the queue. Hope somebody can help me.

*Note: I already tried a lot of broadcasting crates, but never got it to work*

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
ring = { version = "0.16.20" }
multiqueue = { version ="0.3.2" }
```

main.rs

```rs
use core::time;
use multiqueue;
use ring::rand::{SecureRandom, SystemRandom};
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::{net::TcpListener, thread};
```

```rs
const RND_SIZE: usize = 1024;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let (tx, rx) = multiqueue::broadcast_queue(32);

    let sr = SystemRandom::new();
    let mut randoms: [u8; RND_SIZE] = [0; RND_SIZE];

    let socket = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?;

    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        // RNG
        sr.fill(&mut randoms).unwrap();

        // Random bytes into broadcasting queue
        tx.try_send(randoms).ok();

        let sleep_duration = time::Duration::from_millis(100);
        thread::sleep(sleep_duration);
    });

    // Handle different client connections
    for stream in socket.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(mut stream) => {
                // Adding a separate stream to the queue which is owned by the thread below
                let rx = rx.add_stream();
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    let mut i = 0;
                    for received in rx {
                        println!("Sending {:?}", i);
                        i = i + 1;
                        // Sending bytes to the connected client
                        stream.write_all(&received).ok();
                    }
                });
            }
            Err(_) => {}
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL:**

First of all, I'm fairly new to Rust.
I want to implement a simple server in Rust that is constantly streaming random bytes to different clients (high throughput is essential). A client should be able to subscribe and unsubscribe to/from the stream. It is crucial that all clients receive the same random bytes, therefore some kind of chunking with identifiers must take place.

*Code removed because of length*

Comment: Hello, you know multicasting? https://bluejekyll.github.io/blog/posts/multicasting-in-rust/

Comment: I already tried using a multicast address but it gave me some strange results and only a few bytes came through. I also don't know enough to be able to tell how multicasting would work outside a private network.
Nevertheless, I'll take a closer look into the article you mentioned.